# Adding field path and script into form relative to template path

Tags: joomla-3.x, custom-field, external-script

**Case 1**

I am trying to add field path into `templateDetails.xml` without specifying a templateName. The following code works

```
<fieldset name="name" label="label" addfieldpath="/templates/templateName/fields">
```

But I wonder if it's possible to do something like this

```
<fieldset name="name" label="label" addfieldpath="__DIR__/fields">
```

**Case 2**

Also, the field in question is loading it's own JavaScript file via

```
JHtml::_('script', '/templates/templateName/js/field.js' );
```

works fine, but giving it absolute path doesn't work

```
JHtml::_('script', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)).'/js/fieldName.js' );
```

I know `JHtml::script` is deprecated in Joomla 4, but is still not working for me for some reason.

Thanks for any hint/suggestion.

Comment: Any reason why you would like to have abstolute path instead of relative one?

Comment: As you can see I used `dirname()` to get the absolute path, but I only want to avoid using templateName so I can reuse that field in other extensions.